# Effectivly resize bitmaps onDraw

Tags: android, android-view, android-bitmap

I'm trying to extend some [View](https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view) that displays image and allows to scale it with gestures.

I want to transform it to some kind of map, simply adding small icons over it. To do this, I need to resize icon bitmaps on each draw (or may be im wrong).

Currently I do it like this:

```
private void resizeBitmaps() {
        final float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi;
        for (Bitmap b : activeBitmaps) {
            final float w = (density / 420f) * b.getWidth() * getScale();
            final float h = (density / 420f) * b.getHeight() * getScale();
            final Bitmap result = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, (int) w, (int) h, true);
            if (result != null) {
                resizedBitmaps.put(b, result);
            }
        }
        invalidate();
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    ...
    resizeBitmaps();

    for (MapIcon i : activeIconList) {
        final Bitmap b = resizedBitmaps.get(i.getResource());
        // Center bitmaps;
        if (b != null) {
            final PointF p = new PointF();
            sourceToViewCoord(i.getLocation(), p);
            final float vX = p.x - b.getWidth() / 2;
            final float vY = p.y - b.getHeight() / 2;
            canvas.drawBitmap(b, vX, vY, paint);
        }
    }
}
```

Of course I understand this is a bad solution. When it is scaled too much, it starts lagging. I tried to do the same in several threads, but  just got another problem.

Pleaser help me to fix.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for something like this: https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view

Comment: I'm already use it, problem in scaling done by me.